# Getting Only the first result of a DOM xPath query

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Let's say I have this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('sample.html');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xp->query("//input[@id='honey']");
```

How do I get the content of the attribute `value` of the first result only, since I'm only expecting one result (without using a foreach loop). I tried `var_dump`-ing the result but it can't. I also tried `current($result)->getAttribute('value')` but not luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access it via the following method:

```
$value = $result->item(0)->attributes()->getNamedItem("value")->nodeValue;
```

Comment: The downside to this is that in case of no results it will throw an exception because there's no check if `$result->item(0)` is `null`. I fix this by prefixing the line with a `@` to suppress the error and return null. `$value = @$result->item(0)->attributes()->getNamedItem("value")->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 3):

**Just evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
(//input[@id='honey'])[1]/@value
```

This selects the attribute `value` of the first `input` element in the XML document, the string value of whose `id` attribute is `"honey"`.

**If you want to get not the `value` attribute, but its string value, use**:

```
string((//input[@id='honey'])[1]/@value)
```